# Persistent Virtual Machine Process

Tags: ruby, ssh, process, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud Platform and have a virtual machine. I'm also messing around with webscrapers.

I'm currently trying to do a simple scrape of reddit using a ruby script. That part works pretty well. It essentially continues down and down (to the end of reddit!) scrape the articles, though this, obviously takes some time.

Right now, in order to scrape (I'm running `ruby scrape.rb > reddit.txt`) I have to keep the google virtual machine ssh browser window open on my computer or the process will exit (which makes enough sense). However, what I'd like to do is have the process persist even if I close the window.

Is there a way to somehow have this process continue to run? Then I can periodically log in and check `reddit.txt` which will continue to grow even I'm not ssh'ed in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection).

The command `nohup` is exactly what I was looking for!